# Is my DFA optimal?

Tags: graphs, formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

I designed this FSM graph to demonstrate a DFA that would accept any string that

- is of length 5,
- must contain a *d*,
- can only have *a*s and/or *b*s before the *d*, and
- can only have *b*s and/or *c*s after the *d*.

Here is what I came up with:

[image]

I was wondering if there is any way to improve the graph, by, for example, using fewer states?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems mimimal to me.

You can actually prove that the DFA is minimal by applying the [Myhill-Nerode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) theorem. Two states $p$ and $q$ can not be merged if they can be "distinguished" in the sense that there is a string $w$ such that from exactly one on the two states $w$ leads to a final state. Here you can easily see that all states can be distinguished, and hence must be necessary.

Quick explanation: horizontally the states can be distinguished by their length, vertically by the letter $d$.